# How to unite several results of a dataframe columns describe() into one dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I am applying describe() to several columns of my dataframe, for example:

```
raw_data.groupby("user_id").size().describe()
raw_data.groupby("business_id").size().describe()
```

And several more, because I want to find out how many data points are there per user on average/median/etc..

My question is, each of those calls returns something that seems to be an unstructured output. Is there an easy way to combine them all to a single new dataframe which columns will be: [count,mean,std,min,25%,50%,75%,max] and the index will be the various columns described?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might simply build a new DataFrame manually.  If you have

```
>>> raw_data
   user_id  business_id  data
0       10            1     5
1       20           10     6
2       20          100     7
3       30          100     8
```

Then the results of `groupby(smth).size().describe()` are just another `Series`:

```
>>> raw_data.groupby("user_id").size().describe()
count    3.000000
mean     1.333333
std      0.577350
min      1.000000
25%      1.000000
50%      1.000000
75%      1.500000
max      2.000000
dtype: float64
>>> type(_)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

and so:

```
>>> descrs = ((col, raw_data.groupby(col).size().describe()) for col in raw_data)
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_items(descrs).T
             count      mean      std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
user_id          3  1.333333  0.57735    1    1    1  1.5    2
business_id      3  1.333333  0.57735    1    1    1  1.5    2
data             4  1.000000  0.00000    1    1    1  1.0    1
```

Instead of `from_items` I could have passed a dictionary, e.g.
`pd.DataFrame({col: raw_data.groupby(col).size().describe() for col in raw_data}).T`, but this way the column order is preserved without having to think about it.

If you don't want all the columns, instead of `for col in raw_data`, you could define `columns_to_describe = ["user_id", "business_id"] etc` and use `for col in columns_to_describe`, or use `for col in raw_data if col.endswith("_id")`, or whatever you like.